# Executing sudo make install in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, makefile, installation

I'm contributing to OpenCV using Eclipse Neon.

I edited the Build command in Project->Proprieties->C/C++ Build->Build command as `sudo make -j8 install`, so when I build the project, Eclipse compiles OpenCV and then install it in my system.

However, this is the returned error:

```
sudo make -j8 install all 
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I think that this is because sudo asks the password and Eclipse can't give it. How can I do this? I've found this [question][1] on the topic, but I didn't understood the given [answer][2]

Comment: What happens when you run make -j8 on the command line? Googling generates some ideas to try.

Comment: Well according to OpenCV documentation would mean that it runs 8 different threads for compiling in parallel (I have 4 cores with 2 contents each), but I don't see how this is related

Comment: You were already running (or attempting to run) with 8 threads. The difference was running a simplified command on the shell prompt to try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `sudo` use an alternative, which uses GUI, like `gksudo` on Gnome / LXDE or `kdesudo` on KDE.

If you want to use `sudo`, you have to put the line

```
john ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/make
```

into the file `/etc/sudoers`, where `john` is your user name and `/usr/bin/make` is the path to the `make` executable. With this line, you can start `make` with `sudo`, but without enter the credentials.

But instead of entering this line directly to `/etc/sudoers`, you should better call `sudo visudo`, which opens the sudoers file in an editor and if you close the program, it checks the changes you made on the file.